# cannot edit Server runtime environment in Eclipse (Oxygen)

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly, jboss-tools

I cannot edit Server runtime environment in Eclipse (Oxygen) after update "JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools" under "JBoss Application Server Adapters" by the following url

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/photon/development/updates/

The updated version is 3.9.200.v20210921-1316

Before update, the version is 3.9.101.v20200403-1526 that I can edit the server for changing location.

When I uninstall the updated version, I cannot re-install the beforehand version.

Please help, thanks.[server runtime env problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14MwM.png)

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is more than four years and 14 releases behind. Keep your Eclipse up to date, not just the plugins you have installed.

Comment: I've updated Eclipse Oxygen by "Check for Updates", but the problem is still existed.  Can I fallback the version of "JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools"?
(note: my team allowed us to use Eclipse Oxygen for development at the moment.)

Comment: Well, in the very past, the latest release update site was not configured as update site by default. When missing to update for years as you did, better install a fresh Eclipse and use a fresh workspace. Note: you and your team are doing wrong by using outdated software. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It seems no workaround if keeping current Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is not current, but retro: more than four years and 14 releases behind. Please makes sure the used software is up to date before asking.

Comment: Sorry that I meant I'm currently using Eclipse Oxygen that my team kept to use this version.

Comment: My workaround now is to re-download the Eclipse Oxygen, and using the default JBoss runtime to edit the server instead of update JBoss [2021-09]

Answer (score 0):

Which JVM do you use to run Eclipse ? Please note that Server Tools is known to have an issue with Java 17

Comment: jdk_open_1.8_64 (Note: before JBoss tools update, the version is 3.9.101.v20200403-1526 that I can edit the server normally)

Comment: What known issue Jeff? I only see one in Bugzilla.

Comment: Please note that latest JBoss Tools requires 2021-09 so can you send the Eclipse log file so we can analyze what's going wrong

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Here is a partial log.  As I'm new with Stack Overflow, I can't find way to attach the log file here. [.....org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.jboss.tools.runtime.ui [2356]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.jboss.tools.foundation.ui; bundle-version="1.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.jboss.tools.foundation.ui; bundle-version="1.6.900.v20210922-1648"; singleton:="true"
       org.jboss.tools.foundation.ui [2347]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))" .....]

Comment: ...container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1634)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1613)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1585)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1528)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1) ...